# fgets() returns false everytime php

Tags: php, html, authentication, webserver

my project's task is simple: read from a file line by line, check if the user and password are stored into "database.txt".
the problem is that "fgets($fd)" returns everytime "FALSE" instead of the string, so when i use strpos or substr the return value is always false.
this is my code, thanks for the help:

```
 <?php
function signin(){

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
        if(empty($_REQUEST['loginuser']) || empty($_REQUEST['loginpsw']))
            return false;
        else{
            $fd = fopen("database.txt","r");
            while(!feof($fd)){
                $line = fgets($fd);
                if(strpos($line,$_REQUEST['loginuser']) !== false){
                    if(substr($line,strrpos($line,",")+1) === sha1($_REQUEST['loginpsw'])){
                        fclose($fd);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        fclose($fd);
            return false;
        }
    }
else return false;
}

if(!signin()){
    header("Location: index.html"); 
}
else {
    header("Location: home.php");
}
?>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="testpage test page keywords aristocats pompelmi cavolfiore" />
        <meta name="author" content ="Alessandro Savona" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Style.css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers" rel="stylesheet"> 
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Inline" rel="stylesheet"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topbar">
            <div class="logo">
                <label>We Like Pepperoni</label>
                </label>

            </div>
            <div class="logo2">
                <img src="https://www.trieste.pizza/resources/images/trieste-pizza-logo.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

again, thank you for the help!

EDIT:

the value of $fd is 5
it's located in the path /var/www/html
that is the file:

```
###########################################################
#     name surname,username,password SHA1(Rowling)        #
###########################################################
Harry Potter,potter,f5043f5cb1f52071e96a44303919b88179eb7bad
Ron Weasley,weasley,f5043f5cb1f52071e96a44303919b88179eb7bad
Hermione Granger,granger,f5043f5cb1f52071e96a44303919b88179eb7bad
Lord Voldemort,voldemort,f5043f5cb1f52071e96a44303919b88179eb7bad
Albus Dumbledore,dumbledore,f5043f5cb1f52071e96a44303919b88179eb7bad
Severus Snape,snape,f5043f5cb1f52071e96a44303919b88179eb7bad
Rubeus Hagrid,hagrid,f5043f5cb1f52071e96a44303919b88179eb7bad
Draco Malfoy,malfoy,f5043f5cb1f52071e96a44303919b88179eb7bad
```

Comment: *check if the user and password are stored into "database.txt"* oh... Passwords stored in a txt? Is that plain text txt also perhaps?

Comment: How big is your database.txt file?

Comment: Where is database.txt located? Did you check the value of `$fd`?

Comment: the value of $fd is 5 and is located in the path /var/www/html

Comment: the question has been edited